# Prove that : $ \frac{1}{w-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{z^{n}}{w^{n+1}}+\frac{z^{N}}{w^{N}(w-z)}$, $|w|>|z|$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $w,z\in\mathbb{C}\\$

The following is known : $|w|>|z|$

Prove that : $ \frac{1}{w-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{z^{n}}{w^{n+1}}+\frac{z^{N}}{w^{N}(w-z)}$  for $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

I tried defining $w=x+iy, z=u+iv$

and stating that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}>\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$

That's it thus far. I'd be happy for some directions please

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit ambiguously written. It would be easier to understand as:

$$\frac{1}{w-z} = \frac{z^{N}}{w^{N}(w-z)} + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{z^{n}}{w^{n+1}} \text{ for } N \in \mathbb{N}$$

so that it doesn't look like

$$\frac{1}{w-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left(\frac{z^{n}}{w^{n+1}}  + \frac{z^{N}}{w^{N}(w-z)}\right) \text{ for } N \in \mathbb{N}$$

which is a very different problem.

After solving this, it looked like the fact that $w$ and $z$ were complex and the fact that $|w|>|z|$ were unimportant aside from the fact that they guaranteed commutativity and that no denominators were $0$.

As for direction, try solving with induction. The base case of $N=1$ should be easy and you should be able to factor things out during the inductive step to make things work. As this might be a homework problem, I won't go into further detail, but at some point the fact that $p\cdot q = (p-1)\cdot q + q$ may be useful.

Comment: Thank you ! I was able to solve it with induction